# How to write custom code on save of Share Point List New Item

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to write custom code on Click of Save, when a new List Item is created in Share Point site.
Which is the easiest and most well controlled way to do that.
I have C# Code to do the stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger custom logic after item saved, there are two solutions.

[SharePoint add-in Remote event receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins)

[SharePoint 2013 workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo)

If you want to trigger event before item saved, check [PresaAction(JavaScript)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38255.use-of-presaveaction-function-on-list-forms-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: So nice of you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggetions

Answer (score 0):

As @Lee stated ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50227124/1785341)) there are a few options.

If you want to run server side code? The option i would go on is Custom code to run an Eventreceiver (not to be confused with Remote eventreceiver). I would prefer this option than doing it by using a remote Event Receiver.

Then you can trigger this on the ItemUpdated or ItemAdded event.

Microsoft's article regarding [How to: Create an Event Receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ee231563(v=vs.120))

Comment: Thanks. It really is useful